# Auto-close HTML tags in Komodo Edit?

Tags: komodo, code-editor, html, auto-close

Is it possible to turn this on in version 6.1.1? I'm not seeing it...

Comment: You may have better chance of getting a response at the ActiveState Community Forum: http://community.activestate.com/forums/komodo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's an app... er... [extension](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/html-toolkit) for that.

---

**Update:** Apparently HTML Toolkit has been [discontinued](http://community.activestate.com/node/6958#comment-17891).  You can still download it here:

http://community.activestate.com/files/htmltoolkit-1.3.1.2-ko.xpi

Installation instructions on the home page here:

http://www.ohloh.net/p/komodo-html-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but as of Komodo Edit 7.1 you can disable this wretched feature using `Edit -> Preferences -> Code Intelligence -> Automatically Insert end tag when typing start tag in HTML/XML documents`.